# IE8 only submits with button, not submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, file-upload

So, this is strange, and it was working for me about a month ago, before I made a bunch of code updates. Anyways the issue is the live submit handler wont even run in IE8, however, if i run it on a button click, it works. See below:

HTML

```
        <label>Add Attachment</label>
        <form class="file_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" action="">
            <input name="binary" id="file" size="27" type="file" /><br />
            <br><input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload" /><br />
            <input type="button" class="test" value="test">
            <iframe class="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style=""></iframe>
        </form>
        <label>Attachments</label>
        <ul class="upload_output">
        <li class="nofiles">(No Files Added, Yet)</li>
        </ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
function file_upload($theform,item_id){
    $theform.attr('ACTION','io.cfm?action=updateitemfile&item_id='+item_id);
    if($theform.find('[type=file]').val().length > 0){
        $('iframe').one('load',function(){
            $livepreview.agenda({
                action:'get',
                id:item_id,
                type:'item',
                callback:function(json){
                    $theform.siblings('.upload_output').append('<li style="display:none" class="file-upload"><a target="blank" href="io.cfm?action=getitemfile&item_file_id='+json[0].files.slice(-1)[0].item_file_id+'">'+json[0].files.slice(-1)[0].file_name+'</a> <a style="color:red" title="Delete file?" href="#deletefile-'+json[0].files.slice(-1)[0].item_file_id+'">[X]</a></li>').children('li').fadeIn();
                    $theform.siblings('.upload_output').find('.nofiles').remove();
                }
            });
            //Resets the file input. The only way to get it cross browser compatible as resetting the val to nothing
            //Doesn't work in IE8. It ignores val('') to reset it.
            $theform.append('<input type="reset" style="display:none">').children('[type=reset]').click().remove();
        });
    }
    else{
        $.alert('No file selected');
        return false;
    }
}
/* FILE UPLOAD EVENTS */
//When they select "upload" in the modal
$('.file_upload').live('submit',function(event){
    alert('hello world');
    file_upload($('.agenda-modal .file_upload'),$('.agenda-modal').attr('data-defaultitemid'));
});
/* This is the code that makes it work..., but i dont want it! it should alert hello world on the submit button! */
$('.test').live('click',function(event){
    $('.file_upload').submit();
});
```

Comment: Just a quick sanity check - are all the urls are being served by the same domain? ie8 brought in some better XSS-defenses so the same origin policy may be more strictly enforced...

Comment: Yeah :( its all the same domain... And like i said, it works when you press the button, just not the submit...

Answer (score 0):

That is by design, and not at all isolated to IE 8. It has always been that way, in all browsers.

The `submit` event doesn't happen if you call the `submit` method, only when you submit the form using the submit button.

Comment: So... how do I fix this? It was working, well, the live submit was working before I made code updates, and i can just hide the submit button and make a input type="button" button and have that click handler, its just ugly...

Answer (score -1):

1. instead of creating reset button, emulating click event and destroying it -- why not just

   ```
   $('.file_upload').reset();
   ```
2. Do you really need *live* to submit the form? If the button stays in the DOM all the time, make it use the normal click event like

   ```
   $('.test').click(function(){
       $('.file_upload').submit();
   });
   ```

Comment: Reset didn't work in IE8 at all. Just kept it there. Trust me... i think its an ugly looking hack, but .reset() did nothing.

The form isn't static. The form is automagically generated from a sort of "template" within the DOM and it's cloned and manipulated then placed inside of a modal box.